# HOw to get index on click of particlular annotation pin in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps

This is BridgeAnnotation interface which has delegate of MKAnnotation

```
@interface BridgeAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *lat,*lon,*titlevalue,*subtitlevalue;
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSInteger  myindex;
@end
```

I am setting value to **myindex** variable in my method like as below

```
  BridgeAnnotation *bridgeAnnotation = [[BridgeAnnotation alloc] init];
   [bridgeAnnotation setLat:[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%f",theCoordinate.latitude]];
   [bridgeAnnotation setLon:[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%f",theCoordinate.longitude]];
   [bridgeAnnotation setTitlevalue:[PMLObj ProductTitle]];
   [bridgeAnnotation setSubtitlevalue:[[PMLObj ProductPrice] stringByAppendingFormat:@"$"]];
    [bridgeAnnotation setMyindex:i];

   [self.mapView addAnnotation:bridgeAnnotation];
```

THis is my overiding method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;


        static NSString* BridgeAnnotationIdentifier = @"bridgeAnnotationIdentifier";
        MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)
        [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:BridgeAnnotationIdentifier];
        if (!pinView)
        {
            UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];


            NSLog(@"---%d",rightButton.tag);
            [rightButton addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(showDetails:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

            return customPinView;
        }
        else
        {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return pinView;


}
```

In above method I want to access **myindex** of BridgeAnnotation class..
How it possible? OR I have to use other method for that??

Can any one help me?

Comment: hey How are you setting the index in `Bridge Annotation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to capture the annotation on a click then you should use this delegate

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
  BridgeAnnotation *annotation = (BridgeAnnotation *)mapView.annotation;
  NSInteger *yourIndex = annotation.myindex;
}
```